# paypal checkout 2.0 wrong exchange rate, any ideas?

Tags: paypal, currency, checkout

I am integrating paypal checkout 2.0 on my website, but when I enter my credit card to test I realize that paypal does an incorrect currency conversion from any currency to dollars, which ends up giving the client a price lower than what you are actually going to pay, please update the exchange rates on a daily basis to avoid this error

See the picture! ↓↓↓↓ to understand the problem! ↓↓↓↓

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found my problem, when passing the api to real mode the currency exchange is fixed, I hope it can help someone XD